# Android: How to handle a context within an AlarmService

Tags: android

In android (as a beginner) I have created an `AlarmService` class to act as a service, i.e. to run every fixed interval in the background, to check data and probably to notify the user that something is going on.

The `AlarmService` class is defined as follows:

```
public class AlarmService extends Service
{
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm(this);
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        alarm.SetAlarm(this);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        alarm.SetAlarm(this);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and the actual `Alarm` is implemented as follows:

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private Context mContext;
    public final static String LOGHEAD = "StoxxAlarm";

    public Alarm() {
        mContext = null;
    }
    public Alarm(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        int updateInterval = Integer.parseInt(sharedPref.getString("updateInterval", "24")); // ##PROBLEM##
        // ... do something here
    }

    public void SetAlarm(Context context)
    {
        // get the update cylce from the prefences
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        int updateInterval = Integer.parseInt(sharedPref.getString("updateInterval", "24"));

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * updateInterval, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
    }

    public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }
}
```

The problem occurs in the line marked with `##PROBLEM##` as the `context` is `null`. How can I fix the problem?

The funny thing is, that I fixed something else in the code which did not work. Before that fix (related to something else), this kind of worked. But now, how to make sure the function becomes a proper 'context' (what ever this is, I still do not understand properly what a context is...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I fix the problem?

With respect to this specific concern, `mContext` will always be `null`, because Android will not use your one-parameter constructor when it sends you a broadcast. Get rid of `mContext`, and use the `Context` that is passed into `onReceive()`.

Beyond that:

- I do not know why you are returning `START_STICKY`
- I do not know why you are overriding `onStart()` and `onStartCommand()`, given that `onStart()` was deprecated 6-7 years ago
- I do not know why you have `SetAlarm()` and `ClearAlarm()` as methods on `Alarm`, forcing you to create an `Alarm` and then throw it away, instead of having those methods be implemented on the service, or have them be implemented as `static` methods somewhere
- You are using `RTC_WAKEUP`, which is fine, but unless the work you plan to do is sub-millisecond in duration, you really need to use the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` pattern, so you do not tie up the app's main application thread in `onReceive()` and also can keep the device awake

Comment: I see, thanks. As I am said, I am a beginner with android. I am sure I have lots of problems - what else?

Comment: @Alex: I added some more points to my answer. `AlarmManager` is not the sort of thing that I would recommend that a beginner with Android work with.

Comment: I found this example in a tutorial. I know, that about 99.999% of all tutorials are outdated, but I have no other choice. I have no idea what `START_STICKY` means. Can I just delete the `onStart` method? Or do I have to replace it with something else? And are there tutorials which actually show GOOD and WORKING and CONTEMPORARY code?

Comment: @Alex: "I have no idea what START_STICKY means" -- that's an SO question in itself. Basically, it says that your service should be running at all times, even if Android terminates your process to free up system RAM. Apps that use `AlarmManager` should not have services running all the time. "Can I just delete the onStart method?" -- yes. `onStartCommand()` is the replacement; your `onStart()` method will never be called.

Comment: Sorry for the many questions, but developing android is much, much more complicated than doing astrophysical calculations. I mean it!

Comment: @Alex: "And are there tutorials which actually show GOOD and WORKING and CONTEMPORARY code?" -- well, [I have 3,500+ pages of 'em](https://commonsware.com/Android). In general, check the dates on educational materials. Anything older than 18 months may have some issues. Anything older than 3 years is seriously suspect. "developing android is much, much more complicated than doing astrophysical calculations" -- as a former physics major, I'll disagree, but there's a steep learning curve, to be certain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104463/discussion-between-alex-and-commonsware).

Answer (score 0):

instead of `mContext`, you should use `context`

Comment: Fellow reviewers: this _is_ an answer, and seems to address the problem.